# How to prepare a SOAP request using Zeep?

Tags: python, zeep

I'm trying to use a particularly arcane WSDL SOAP service, published here:
https://api.business.govt.nz/registry/resource/_system/governance/apimgt/applicationdata/provider/mbiecreator/DiscussionCorrespondence/v1/documentation/files/DiscussionCorrespondence.zip

The documentation provides an example Soap query:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:list="http://www.iponz.govt.nz/XMLSchema/Discussion/List" xmlns:ser="http://www.iponz.govt.nz/services" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
 <soapenv:Header/>
 <soapenv:Body>
  <ser:getDiscussionList>
   <list:Transaction>
    <list:DiscussionTransactionBody>
     <list:TransactionContentDetails>
      <list:TransactionCode>Get Discussion List</list:TransactionCode>
      <list:TransactionData>
       <list:DiscussionList>
        <list:DiscussionListDetails>
         <list:DiscussionCreationDateFrom>2015-02-10</list:DiscussionCreationDateFrom>
         <list:DiscussionCreationDateTo>2015-02-10</list:DiscussionCreationDateTo>
        </list:DiscussionListDetails>
       </list:DiscussionList>
      </list:TransactionData>
     </list:TransactionContentDetails>
    </list:DiscussionTransactionBody>
   </list:Transaction>
  </ser:getDiscussionList>
 </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

What I would like to do is replicate this raw query using Zeep. How do I do this?
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I found a [tutorial here](https://medium.com/@adriennedomingus/using-zeep-to-make-soap-requests-in-python-c575ea0ee954) that got me onto the right track. Here's my code:

```
from zeep import Client, Settings

#Creation of headerArr is excluded as it's not relevant to the xml produced
headerArr = {}
settings = Settings(strict=False, xml_huge_tree=True,extra_http_headers=headerArr)
client = Client('DiscussionCorrespondence/wsdls/DiscussionCorrespondence.wsdl',
    settings=settings)
requestData = {
    'Transaction': {
        'DiscussionTransactionBody': {
            'TransactionContentDetails': {
                'TransactionCode':'Get Discussion List',
                'TransactionData': {
                    'DiscussionList': {
                        'DiscussionListDetails': {
                                'DiscussionCreationDateFrom':'2015-02-10',
                                'DiscussionCreationDateTo':'2015-02-10',
                        },
                    },
                },
            },
        },
    },
}
res = client.service.getDiscussionList(**requestData)
```

The prettified XML request sent (from a debug log) is:

```
<soap-env:Envelope xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
 <soap-env:Body>
  <ns0:getDiscussionList xmlns:ns0="http://www.iponz.govt.nz/services">
   <ns1:Transaction xmlns:ns1="http://www.iponz.govt.nz/XMLSchema/Discussion/List">
    <ns1:DiscussionTransactionBody>
     <ns1:TransactionContentDetails>
      <ns1:TransactionCode>Get Discussion List</ns1:TransactionCode>
      <ns1:TransactionData>
       <ns1:DiscussionList>
        <ns1:DiscussionListDetails>
         <ns1:DiscussionCreationDateFrom>2015-02-10</ns1:DiscussionCreationDateFrom>
         <ns1:DiscussionCreationDateTo>2015-02-10</ns1:DiscussionCreationDateTo>
        </ns1:DiscussionListDetails>
       </ns1:DiscussionList>
      </ns1:TransactionData>
     </ns1:TransactionContentDetails>
    </ns1:DiscussionTransactionBody>
   </ns1:Transaction>
  </ns0:getDiscussionList>
 </soap-env:Body>
</soap-env:Envelope>
```

This XML is not identical to that in the question, but it should be functionally identical.

Comment: I am coming across the very same problem. In my case zeep's payload says `<soap-env:Body>` where it should say `<soap:Body>`. Are they equivalent? Do they depend on the SOAP version?

Comment: As far as I know, they are identical, but it's not something I've really investigated as I could work with the results that came back. Remember too that they're namespace prefixes, as opposed to namespaces. They refer to an xmlns: attribute defined on the element or one of its containers (normally on the Envelope element).

Comment: "soap-env" is the prefix, which is actually an alias for the namespace, which is a URI.  As long as the URI is "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" then it has the correct namespace.